# Angular2: email already exist as custom Validator?

Tags: validation, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I created a form with Angular2 and I created the following method to check if the email address already exist. Here is my code:

```
checkEmail(): void {
    // FIRST PART
    this.found = false;
    // If user is not Premium...
    if (!this.currentUser.isPremium) {
        //  ...and if user typed something in the input field, then apply validitor for email address
        if (this.myForm.controls.email.value.length > 0) {
            this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators([validateEmail()]);
            this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
        // If user leaves the input field blank or empty the typed input, then apply validator for required
        } else {
            this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
    // If user is Premium...
    } else if (this.currentUser.isPremium) {
        // ...and if user typed something in the input field, then apply validitor for email address
        if (this.myForm.controls.email.value.length > 0) {
            this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators([validateEmail()]);
            this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
        // If user leaves the input field blank or empty the typed input, then remove any validator
        } else {
            this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators(null);
            this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
    }

    // SECOND PART
    // If the input field is valid then check if the email already exist on server...
    if (this.myForm.controls.email.value.length > 0 && this.myForm.controls.email.valid) {
        this.loadingIcon = true;
        this.anagraficaService.getEmail(this.myForm.controls.email.value)
            .then(response => {
                let count = response.recordCount;
                if (count > 0) {
                    this.found = true;
                } else {
                    this.found = false;
                }
                this.loadingIcon = false;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.found = false;
                this.loadingIcon = false;
            });
    }
}
```

To enable the Submit button in the template file, I check for `myForm.valid` and for `found` set to `false`:

```
<button type="submit" class="ui primary button" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!myForm.valid || found">Submit</button>
```

Now, i would like to check for email address if already exists, I mean put the second part of my code in an external file (custom Validator) and then check for email address validity only in the first part of my code. Something like this:

```
this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators([validateEmail(), checkEmailExists()]);
this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Do you have a better idea to reach the same verifications? Any best practice about this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. That's far away from the idea of reactive forms validations.

First of all don't do this

```
this.myForm.controls.email.setValidators([validateEmail()]);
this.myForm.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
```

`setValidators` and `updateValueAndValidity` are the functions you should nearly never call. They are available only for some specific cases like dynamic form behaviour.

In your case you have a static form which you should just **describe** with some validators. Create a custom asynchronous validator and assign it to the `email` `FormControl`. This validator should return an Observable (or a Promise) which resolves either to `null` when everything is fine or to an object with an error, e.g. `{ emailAlreadyExists: true }` if email exists, `{ required: true }` or use a combination of `Validators.required` and your custom async validation.

In the end of the day you should have

```
...
public ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', null, (control: FormControl) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // also add here is premium logic
        let requiredValidationResult = Validators.required(control);

        if (requiredValidationResult) {
          resolve(requiredValidationResult); // this will be {required: true}
          return;
        }

        // and here call your server and call
        //   resolve(null) in case it's fine
        //   resolve({ emailExists: true }) in case it's existing
      });
    })
  });
}
...
```

and that's it.

Comment: With your solution should i have to inject LoginService to a custom validator to see if the user is Premium? Please pay attention to the first part of my code.

Comment: you should not inject anything into a validator because 1. it is in the scope (closure) of your component where LoginService should already be injected  and you can just use it within validator as `this. currentUser` 2. validator is not a target of injection because it is not a component / service

Comment: And how I can call a custom validator AFTER the submit ? I mean, when I POST the form inputs for create a user. The API returns me Ok or KO, the KO can be a 401 -> 'Email already exist'. So how i can handle this error and call a validator to set it has error { emailExists: true } and showing the error message in the template ?