# Angular2: how to apply custom validators in a certain order?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators, angular2-formbuilder

I created an Angular2 form with 2 custom validators that I pass to a `FormControl`:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
    'CF': ['', [Validators.required, customValidator()], asyncCustomValidator()],
});
```

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pDMKtdC5PqFttfraOPqf (it is based on an old Angular2 version).

I would like to reach the following behaviour:

Only if user pass the `required` and `customValidator` tests then the `asyncCustomValidator` can start (and make calls to backend).

How to get this behaviour?

In addition, is there any difference between using `compose` method and putting two or more validators in the same array?

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a third validator, which simply calls both your custom validators in turn?

```
function composedValidator(){
  if(doValidationFirst){
     return doValidationSecond();
  }
  failAndReturn();
}
```

Edit:

Here's an article on "conditional validation" but IMO for your case I'd use the above method instead:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-conditional-validation-in-angular-2-model-driven-forms

That seems like not quite the right tool for you...

Comment: "setValidators and updateValueAndValidity are the functions you should nearly never call" as someone posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41847805/2516399

Comment: I don't really have an argument either way, and I still say my first solution is concise, simple (and thus maintainable) and does exactly what you want.

Comment: How to apply your solution in case of validator used in combination with async validator? Do I apply just the async validator to the `FormControl`?